# Angular Material ui-router display issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am currently using angular material in a web development project. I am also using the UI router to switch between different states.

I have checked that when the content is too big for the UI router view the content is clipped even when a vertical scrollbar is present.

[image: Example]

Please assist in determining how to vertically scroll through all of the content in the  tag.

Please find below the two html files and the appropriate styles (I have added them to the tags for better understanding.

Please find the index html file pertaining to the body:

```
<body layout="row" flex style="height:100%;width: 100%;max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;overflow:inherit">
    <div ui-view class="ng-scope"></div>
</body>
```

Please find below the file that contains the sidebar and the :

```
<div ng-controller="ToolbarController as tc" style="height:100%">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">

            <md-button hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Icon">
                <md-icon md-svg-src='webui/icons/menu.svg' ng-click="tc.toggleList()" ></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <h2>V-Tchilling</h2>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div layout-fill layout="row" flex>

    <md-sidenav  md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" md-component-id='snav'  class="md-whiteframe-4dp" style="height: 100%" >

        <md-content role="navigation">
            <img class="png-icon" style="max-width: 80%; width: 50%;align-self: center;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 10px;" src="webui/icons/logo.png">
            <ul class="side-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="section in tc.menuService.sections" class="parent-list-item"
            ng-class="{'parentActive' : tc.isSectionSelected(section)}">
          <h2 class="menu-heading" ng-if="section.type === 'heading'"
              id="heading_{{ section.name | nospace }}">
            {{section}}
          </h2>
          <menu-link section="section" ng-if="section.type === 'link'"></menu-link>
          <menu-toggle section="section" ng-if="section.type === 'toggle'"></menu-toggle>
        </li>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
      </ul>


        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>


        <md-content layout-fill  flex md-scroll-y class="_md layout-column flex">
            <ui-view style="align-content: center;" layout-padding flex="noshrink" class="_md layout_padding ng-scope flex-noshrink"  name="content"></ui-view>
        </md-content>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Please find below the code fragment that has the md card:

```
<div style='margin-left: 30px;margin-top: 10px' class="doc-content">
    <h1 style='margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom:0px' class='md-display-2'>Register User</h1>

    <div style='margin-top: 30px;'>
        <md-card  style='width: 75%;height: 10%; max-height: 90%;' flex>
            <md-toolbar class="md-hue-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >
                <h3 class='md-title' style='margin-left: 10px'> User Registration form </h3>
            </md-toolbar>

            <div style='margin-left: 20px'>

                <p class="md-body-2" ng-show='rc.error' style='color:red;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 2px;'> {{rc.error}} </p>

                <form name="registerForm">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-has-placeholder vt-input-container">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" ng-model="rc.user.email" name="email" required>

                        <div ng-messages="registerForm.email.$error" role="alert" multiple="">
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">You must supply an email address</div>
                            <div ng-message="email" class="my-message">Please correct your e-mail address eg: management@vTchill.co.mz</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-has-placeholder vt-input-container">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="password" ng-model="rc.user.firstName" name="firstName" required>

                        <div ng-messages="registerForm.firstName.$error" role="alert" multiple="">
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">You must supply your first name</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-has-placeholder vt-input-container">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="password" ng-model="rc.user.surname" name="surName" required>

                        <div ng-messages="registerForm.surName.$error" role="alert" multiple="">
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">You must supply your surname</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-has-placeholder vt-input-container" required>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" ng-model="rc.user.password" name="password">

                        <div ng-messages="registerForm.password.$error" role="alert" multiple="">
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">You must supply a password</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-has-placeholder vt-input-container" >
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" ng-model="rc.user.confirmPassword" compare-to="rc.user.password" required>

                        <div ng-messages="registerForm.confirmPassword.$error" role="alert" multiple="">
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">Please confirm a confirmation password</div>
                            <div ng-message="compareTo" class="my-message">The passwords do not match</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block md-input-has-placeholder vt-input-container">
                        <label>Phone number</label>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="rc.user.phoneNumber"  ng-pattern="/^2588[0-9]{8}/" md-maxlength="12" name="phoneNumber" required>
                        <div ng-messages="registerForm.phoneNumber.$error" role="alert" multiple="">
                            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">Please provide a phone number </div>
                            <div ng-message="md-maxlength" class="my-message">The number supplied is too long</div>
                            <div ng-message="pattern" class="my-message">Please supply a number in the format 258+(phoneNumber)</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="!registerForm.$valid && !isSubmitted" class="md-hue-2 md-raised md-primary" ng-click="rc.registerUser()">Login</md-button>
                        <div flex="flex"></div>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

        </md-card>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `md-content`.

```
<md-content flex layout="column|row" ui-view></md-content>
```